# OWIN Startup fails

Tags: owin

I'm trying to add asp.net Identity to my web app (Forms) and I'm stuck with an error when I run the app.
I followed this tutorial "Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project" it compiles with no errors but it fails when starting with

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>
> - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
> - The given type or method 'IdentiyTeste.Startup' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly.
>   To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.

I have the Startup.cs class created and placed the key in the appSettings as follows

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(IdentiyTeste.Startup))]
namespace IdentiyTeste
{  
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<add key="owin:appStartup" value="IdentiyTeste.Startup" />
```

I tried all the variations on "OWIN Startup Class Detection" with no success.

I'll place here my .dll list just in case it might help

http://i58.tinypic.com/2r7lpgg.jpg

I added a breakpoint to the Startup class but it never gets to that breakpoint so I think it as something to do with VS2015 configuration to enable Owin Startup or something with the ISS Express VS2015 runs internally but I cant find anything that helps to trace the problem.

Comment: I don't have the permission to add more than 1 link so here are the links to the tutorials 
"Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project" ((http://goo.gl/QpKzqB )

"OWIN Startup Class Detection"  ( http://goo.gl/mv9LOV )

Comment: do you have installed  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb?

Comment: @AntonPutau Thank you for answering. Yes I do have that package installed, the link of the screenshot of dll's shows that package.

Answer (score 0):

you also need Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package otherwise Startup is not called

Comment: Thank you for answering. That package is installed, the link to the .jpg shows that package there. I noticed now that the link might not be working correctly so I will post it again. http://s7.postimg.org/87pdrqfq3/nuget_List.jpg 
Any other ideas?